# How to receive scriptNotify from html in appdata on UWP c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows-10, uwp

Windows won't let my WebView_ScriptNotify Event receive a call if the html is loaded from ms-appdata.

I'm aware that I can use the ms-appx-web protocol to load such a file from my app bundle, but this is no option because the data to show are downloaded after install of the app.
I also can't just use webView.navigateToString because this won't include the referenced libraries in the html file.

Currently I'm trying something like this in my Class.xaml.cs

```
 WebView webView = new WebView();
 webView.ScriptNotify += WebView_ScriptNotify;
 Uri navigationUri = new Uri(@"ms-appdata:///local/index.html");
 webView.Navigate(navigationUri);
```

and

```
 private void WebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ScriptNotifyValue: " + e.Value);
        //I want to do the magic here, but this will never be called
    }
```

in the html file is

```
<div id="content">
     <div class="btn" onClick="window.external.notify('hello world');"</div>
</div>
```

Furthermore, it's no option to use InvokeScript(), because I don't know when the event must be fired and the values for it.

Yet it's mandatory to use files from ms-appdata.

Do you know a solution for this?
Even an alternative workaroung would amaze me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ref [Script notify changes in XAML](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/07/17/whats-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1):

> For content to be able to send notifications the following conditions apply:
>
> - The source of the page should be from the local system via **NavigateToString()**, **NavigateToStream()** or **ms-appx-web:///**
>
> Or
>
> - The source of the page is delivered via **https://** and the site domain name is listed in the app content URI’s section of the package manifest.

So to solve this issue, we can use **[WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx)** with the protocol `ms-local-stream://`, rather than `ms-appdata://`. For example:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // The 'Host' part of the URI for the ms-local-stream protocol needs to be a combination of the package name
        // and an application-defined key, which identifies the specific resolver, in this case 'MyTag'.

        Uri url = webView.BuildLocalStreamUri("MyTag", "index.html");
        StreamUriWinRTResolver myResolver = new StreamUriWinRTResolver();

        // Pass the resolver object to the navigate call.
        webView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri(url, myResolver);
    }

    private void webView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ScriptNotifyValue: " + e.Value);
    }
}

public sealed class StreamUriWinRTResolver : IUriToStreamResolver
{
    public IAsyncOperation<IInputStream> UriToStreamAsync(Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        string path = uri.AbsolutePath;

        // Because of the signature of the this method, it can't use await, so we
        // call into a seperate helper method that can use the C# await pattern.
        return GetContent(path).AsAsyncOperation();
    }

    private async Task<IInputStream> GetContent(string path)
    {
        // We use app's local folder as the source
        try
        {
            Uri localUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local" + path);
            StorageFile f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(localUri);
            IRandomAccessStream stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
            return stream;
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw new Exception("Invalid path"); }
    }
}
```

For more info, please see **Remarks** and **Examples** in [WebView.NavigateToLocalStreamUri method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetolocalstreamuri.aspx) and also **Custom URI resolving** in [What’s new in WebView in Windows 8.1](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/07/17/whats-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1). Besides, there is also a [WebView control (XAML) sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlWebView) on GitHub.