# Xamarin Forms WebView control in UWP app can't load url but Edge browser and Android app can

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a C# Xamarin Forms app that has a very simple Xaml page that contains a WebView control that won't render an HTML page I created when I run it as a UWP app.  A previous version of this HTML page worked fine in the UWP version but I added some async JavaScript code and perhaps some other problematic JavaScript and now I just get a blank page in Xamarin Forms UWP app and nothing renders.  This same HTML page works fine in the Edge browser and when running as an Android app running in the Android Emulator so it appears to be an issue with the WebView control in UWP with the specific HTML I have included below. I have Internet and Microphone capabilities turned on in the UWP manifest.

I am testing this in Visual Studio 2019 using Xamarin Forms 4.7.0.968 and Xamarin Essentials 1.5.3.2 and Microsoft.NETCore.Universal 6.2.10.

[**Update:** followed tip on debugging and now see an error][There is no errors or exceptions thrown so I can't tell what the issue is.  Anyone have any ideas on why the HTML page below won't render in UWP app or what I can do to debug... I wish I had something like the F12 tools in the browser so I could tell what is going wrong.]

After following the tip on debugging from (Nico Zhu - MSFT), here is the error I saw which points to line with the argument to the call to createDirectLineSpeechAdapters().  Apparently, the UWP WebView is not happy with passing that async() function as a parameter to createDirectLineSpeechAdapters():

[image]

Both the Edge browser and the WebView control in the Android version of this app work fine so I am trying to understand why this is a problem for the UWP implementation of WebView.

Here is the HTML code that won't render with the XAML following it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script crossorigin="anonymous"
            src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        #webchat {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-es5.js"></script>
    <script>
        (async function () {
            const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
                if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
                        payload: {
                            name: 'webchat/join',
                            value: {
                                language: window.navigator.language
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return next(action);
            });

            const settings = {
                locale: 'en-us',
                store,
                userID: 'MyUId'
            };

            let adapters = null;

            const fetchCredentials = async () => {
                const region = 'eastus';
                const response = await fetch(`https://${region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken`, {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
                        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<my key>'
                    }
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Failed to fetch authorization token.');
                }

                const authorizationToken = await response.text();
                return { authorizationToken, region };
            };

            adapters = await window.WebChat.createDirectLineSpeechAdapters({
                fetchCredentials
            });

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                {
                    ...adapters,
                    ...settings
                },
                document.getElementById('webchat'));

            document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
        })().catch(err => console.error(err));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the XAML that shows how the WebView looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:windows="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.WindowsSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Fasst.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="Assistant" Clicked="AssistantButton_Clicked" />
            <Button Text="Map" Clicked="MapButton_Clicked" />
        </StackLayout>
        <BoxView x:Name="mapPane" IsVisible="false" Color="Blue" />
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <WebView x:Name="assistantPane" Source="https://fasstassistant-rhw.azurewebsites.net/Index" windows:WebView.IsJavaScriptAlertEnabled="true"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Could you share c# code that use to load html content?

Comment: Ok, I added that info to the original question

Answer (score 2):

> . I wish I had something like the F12 tools in the browser so I could tell what is going wrong.

For debugging WebView control in UWP app, you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-a-webview-control?view=vs-2017).

We need to use the **DOM Explorer** to inspect and debug a WebView control, and you could also use [Microsoft Edge DevTools Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-edge-devtools-preview/9mzbfrmz0mnj?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) to test this UWP webView control. For my testing html page throw issuetoken access denied.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you.  The issuetoken access error is to be expected since the sample requires a subscription key to be passed for the call to be successful

Comment: So, please follow above step to debug webview control and  share the error you have.

Comment: Ok, I follow the debugging steps and have updated the question with the results.  Any idea what its telling me?

Comment: Which is the webview load html file or Source url?

Comment: The HTML is the webpage that the WebView is trying to load.  I am the author of that HTML webpage and can change it if need be.  The XAML is WebView that is loading that  HTML page.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: Yep, I tried load html page with official code sample, for the policy, we can't touch customer's auth token, so we can't test further, can you try this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithwebview/) code and replace the local html file with yours?

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the sample and replaced the html file with my html and got the very same non-working behavior.  App runs with no errors but a blank page.  Is there something else I can try now that I have this sample with my HTML?   


            adapters = await window.WebChat.createDirectLineSpeechAdapters({
                fetchCredentials
            });

            window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
                {
                    ...adapters,
                    ...settings
                },
                document.getElementById('webchat'));

Comment: May you need  add the the source (https://fasstassistant-rhw.azurewebsites.net/Index) into uwp Content URIs for more please refer this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56425396/7254781).

Comment: zhu - microsoft, Ok, I will try that but not totally clear on how.  Are you saying that I should move the page from the share PCL to the UWP project.  I read the link you provided and it didn't help clear that question up for me.  Is all I need to do is move it the the UWP project or is there other steps I need to take as well, please explain.  Also, can you explain how you think this will help?  Just want to understand what I am doing and why we think it will help.

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view#interacting-with-web-view-content)

Comment: That last link you provided refers to InvokeScriptAsync() which is not defined in Xamarin Forms 4.7.0.968 that I am using or it's an extension method of some kind.  Should I be able to call that?

Comment: Xamarin Forms has same method `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` for more detail please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#invoking-javascript).